Parallel calculation of several custom formulas in LibreOfficeCalc
I wrote a custom formula in Python (for example, the name Formula 1) and added it as an extension of LibreOfficeCalc.
There can be a lot of such formulas on the sheet and with different parameters.
Is it possible to somehow force LibreOffice Calc to execute these formulas in any way now I have sequentially, but in parallel?

Are you asking because of performance? Or, if the formulas need to be executed in a different order, then there's likely a logical problem with how you've set it up, and you would need to rethink it.

Before continuing this discussion, take a look at other posts around the web about execution order, such as https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=103276 and https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/calc-cell-resolution-order-formula-exectuion-order/52358/7. Then, explain further what you want to do and why.

Yes, because of the need to reduce the execution time of formulas. The main thing is that the data should be correct according to the result of the execution.

I want several unrelated formulas to be executed not sequentially, but in parallel and, accordingly, the total execution time is reduced.

I agree with erAck's solution to your post at https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/parallel-calculation-of-several-custom-formulas-in-libreofficecalc/108283. Do the work in parallel in python and get the results to be sequentially entered into Calc. However, keep in mind that spreadsheet speed can typically be improved by changing the order or method of formulas, rather than trying to execute in parallel. Take a look at this post to get an idea: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-can-i-make-libreoffice-multi-threaded/18749.
